# Implementing carousel cards with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to create with the help of bootstrap cards that appear on the normal desktop and on the mobile to be a carousel type like the ones on the google page in the "Resources" category.
Example: https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/tag-manager/

Can anyone help me how I can implement this carousel time?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePAHK.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Swiper JS](https://swiperjs.com/demos#css-mode), [Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/), [Tiny-swiper](https://tiny-swiper.joe223.com/), [Slick](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), [Keen-slider](https://keen-slider.io/), [Glide.js](https://glidejs.com/)(OLD), [Owl-carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/)
the Google one is `transform: translate` based not scroll

A slider made using CSS scroll-snap would be resposive & lightweight, and will work great especially on mibile devices
Try [THIS](https://smolcss.dev/#smol-scroll-snap) on your phone

AND if you want cursor support use some Javascript as described [HERE](https://htmldom.dev/drag-to-scroll/)